# Find the sum of all even digits in a given integer

Tags: javascript

This codes gives me the number of even digit in a number... Actually I want to add that number.

```js
var value = 2234,
sum = 0;

while (value) {
  sum += value % 10;
  value = Math.floor(value / 10);
}
console.log(sum);
```

Comment: you want to add the event digits in a number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution convert to array use `Array.from` and use `reduce` function.

It may be not best way.

```js
var value = 2234
var total = Array.from(String(2234), Number).reduce((acc, item)=>{
   if(item % 2 == 0){
     acc += item;
   }
   return acc;
},0);

console.log(total);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get a digit and check if the digit is evan, then add the digit to sum.

```js
var value = 2234,
    digit,
    sum = 0;

while (value) {
    digit = value % 10; 
    if (digit % 2 === 0) sum += digit;
    value = Math.floor(value / 10);
}

console.log(sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var value = 2234,
sum = 0;

while (value) {
    if((value%10)%2 === 0) //check if digit is even
        sum += value % 10;
    value = Math.floor(value / 10);
}

console.log(sum);
```